# 2 uitableview in the same uiview issue

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have 2 uitableview settings and searchResult as following

```
IBOutlet UITableView* Settings ; 
IBOutlet UITableView* SearchResult; 

@property ( nonatomic , retain ) IBOutlet UITableView* Settings ; 
@property ( nonatomic , retain ) IBOutlet UITableView* SearchResult;
```

to diffrentiate between them in the tableview delegate and source I search by the table name

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (tableView == Settings ) {

        return 2;

    } else {

        return 0 ;
    }
}
```

the second table never fire the events , I mean the settings table work very well , but the second never fire the events  even I set its datasource, and delegeate to file owner

also `[self.SearchResult reloadData];` never fire the events 
any suggestion to solve that

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the number of sections in the second table be 1 instead of 0? **The second table will not be visible if the number of sections is 0**..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if(tableView == Settings )
    {

        return 2;
    }
    return 1; // Called for second table
}
```

Comment: when change it to 1 it give exec_bad_ccess

Comment: I guess the error is somewhere else on your cellForRow. Try removing the second return to see if u get the second table.

Answer (score 1):

Have you manually set the delegate and datasource for both the tables??? If not set it... This might help

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    NSInteger *returnValue = 0;

    if ([tableView isEqual:Settings]{
        NSLog (@"Settings did called datasource methods");
        returnValue = 2; // number of sections in your table - if you have NSArray datasource use [datasource count] ;

    } else if ([tableView isEqual:SearchResult"){
        NSLog (@"SearchTable did called datasource methods);
        returnValue = 1; // or count of that datasource
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

This might help to debug